# Игнорировать текущую директорию

Tags: .htaccess, php

Всем привет! Сайт работает по модульной системе `$uri = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` и получает на `$uri[1]` основной модуль, ищет его в папке и инклюдит. При размещении сайта в директории (`cabinet`) он уже на основной модуль автоматом принимает `cabinet`, не находит такого модуля и выдает 404. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как игнорировать текущую папку?
`.htaccess` настроен следующим образом:

```
RewriteEngine On            
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-f
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-d
RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ index.php [N]

RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-f
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

Comment: @kohana не работает :(

Comment: >  При размещении сайта в директории
> (cabinet) он уже на основной модуль
> автоматом принимает cabinet, не
> находит такого модуля и выдает 404.

Я это предложение просто умственно не осилил.

Comment: @kohana, в общем, все работает так: index.php имеет переменную $uri = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']). Затем я проверяю, есть ли такой модуль ($uri[1]) в папке с модулями, если есть - подключаю. Так вот, здесь $uri[1] равен cabinet, вместо пустоты. Нужно игнорировать текущую директорию.

Comment: @kohana прошу помогите!

Comment: @kohana короче говоря, нужно сделать так, чтобы $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] не видел папку cabinet и в массиве под номером 1 $uri[1] была пустота. Как будто index.php находится в корневой директории.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}    !-d
```

убрать, не?

Comment: Хотя неправильно понял вопрос, покажите пример вашего URL, с которого вы хотите игнорировать директорию.

Comment: @Manitikyl http://site.ru/cabinet/ - вот, нужно чтобы .htaccess игнорировал cabinet и $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] не видел его.

Comment: Проблема актуальна! Прошу помощи!